# Convert SVG string to base64 PNG on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svg, base64, png

I am trying to find a solution in an ASP.NET MVC API (v 5.2.7) for converting an SVG element to a base64 encoded PNG string so I can allow the user to copy and paste the image to their Google Doc.  Google Doc does not support SVG.

The SVG element is stored in a database. For example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="mySVG" width="288" height="386" class="ot-item-hotspot">
    <image href="/graphics/393294.png" width="288" height="386"></image>
    <circle cx="167.5" cy="42" r="10" class="hotspot-element" data-value="1"></circle>
    <circle cx="129.5" cy="84" r="10" class="hotspot-element" data-value="2"></circle>
    <circle cx="137.5" cy="163" r="10" class="hotspot-element" data-value="3"></circle>
</svg>
```

I could using a HTML canvas object to load the SVG and get the base64 PNG string but I would prefer to do this on the server and simply return the base64 string.

I have found a few libraries on GitHub and other repositories but I am looking for something on the server side.  Is that possible with SVG that relies on the browser for processing?

Comment: You may try a server side conversion via libraries like imagemagick. The main problem with serverside/headless conversions: "modern" svg may heavily leverage CSS – so a svg parser also needs to include a quite advanced CSS parser. In contrast: converting svgs client-based via `<canvas>`  and canvas to datURL has the huge advantage you already  have the most advanced svg parsing environment without putting extra load on your server by installing an extra library. You can actually render the svg as a regular image even converting it to any web image format (png, jpg, wepb)